# How to convert excel date format in SQL with datetime datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with column varchar contains date in different formats. I need to convert that to date and store in another table. Below is the example of sample data which is failing.

```
declare @dts table(DTs varchar(50))

insert into @dts
select '13/12/2017'
union
select '12/13/2017'


select convert(date,dts,103) from @dts
```

Comment: So if you have the date `01/12/2017`, how do you know whether this is January or December? If you can't tell, your dbms can't either. In other words, even if you *can* convert to a datetime, there is no guarantee it is converted to the *right* datetime.

Comment: simply add case expression in above `select convert(date, dts, case  when left(dts, 2) <= 12 then 101 else 103 end) from @dts`

Comment: This select should not fail. Please provide the insert code. Is the datatype of the destination table a date? You are also mentioning excel. Are you sure excel provides the string you have manually typed in your example? How are you moving data from excel?

Comment: @YogeshSharma, Do you seriously suggest all first 12 days of every month should be converted to their numerical month counterpart? It may remove conversion errors, but will create wrong results.

Comment: @HoneyBadger in above both have 13 dates as i have suggest simple `case` expression nothing else